# Weird people and their Karma

Tags: karma

So many times I've read and watched in news that people are taking video in their phone while crime is happening and someone burning in fire, one badly bleeding and facing to the death. So does those people are mostly reasonable cause of victims death?

Do they need to pay more than actual criminal when they could save them?
I thought they are real criminals. I'm really afraid what's happening in this "Modern weird world". If I were there I could save those people. I'm really feel very very bad cause I couldn't help them out.People just taking video to viral on social medias. I really don't understand this kind of nature.

So what is waiting for them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The uncaring kamma will probably affect their life in ways such as problems with their relationships, etc, & also contribute to a bad world, which, if not corrected, will bring a worse world in the future. This is what is waiting for them, namely, *hell on earth*, either for them; for their family; for their friends; or for their children. As for the hell you seem to be imagining, this is only of the *imagination*.

But if you realise the results of kamma are felt within the heart & also manifest in the quality of relationships & the world, then you will understand a lack of care inwardly brings a lack of care outwardly. This present "weird world" you see is itself the result of the kamma of not caring. There is no requirement to "wait" because the results of uncaring kamma have already come to fruition.

Comment: @Dhmmadhatu Thanks for your priceless time and answer.